# 404s appearing in console when loading XPM

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, 2013-sp1

When we load our pages in XPM the browser console appears to be showing several 404s for resources:

```
http://localhost/SDL/Common/ApplicationHost/ApplicationHost/Views/Frame/cultures/frame.en-US.js?1.0.0.1253
```

I checked on the CMS server and there's only 6 non-English frame JS files, nothing for en-US.

A call from **Editor_v7.1.0.66.10_.aspx** seems to be looking for `se_blank.html` returns 404.

We also have a couple of exceptions:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
Tridion.Utils.Object.deserialize 
Tridion.Utils.CrossDomainMessaging._messageHandler 
f.executeListener 
a

Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
Tridion.Utils.Object.deserialize 
Tridion.Utils.CrossDomainMessaging._messageHandler 
f.executeListener 
a
```

Is our installation just knackered?!?

**UPDATE**

So the se_blank.html appears to be normal XPM behaviour, but as our application is DD4T we need to handle that route.

Answer (score 5):

In my XPM DD4T implementations se_blank.html is hardcoded in the controller to return an empty page with status 200 HTTP code - once thats in place, XPM will work normally again.

The missing culture file is "normal" - we raised a ticket with support and they said this was intentional.

Comment: Thanks Rogier - so you have the missing culture file?

Comment: Updated my answer - missed that part :)

Comment: What about when the staging webapp is running under another context root than /? In that case its no use putting se_blank.html in the webapp root, nor publishing it, since the request for se_blank never reaches the webapp. Any solutions for this, apart from an additional webapp running under / containing only se_blank.html?

Comment: I usually use an apache/ngnx proxy to make sure the applications are routed correctly and protect the appserver. Such a proxy server could also host the se_blank.html, or relay into a different context depending on your needs.