# XPM Rich Text editor - Bold, Italics, Underline functionality not working

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, rtf

While editing content in the rich text field using Rich Text editor pop up window (within XPM) - bold, italics and underline functionality is not working.
Whereas these functionalities are working fine using Ribbon Toolbar buttons. It is also working fine if short cut keys (`ctrl+b`, `ctrl+i`, `ctrl+u` ) are used.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: By not working do you mean the rich text lacks styling? When you mention the rich text format area works with Ribbon Toolbar and shortcut keys, is that only in the Component form view?

Comment: I mean rich text editor not working as expected in case of using rich text editor popup window (properties box) in XPM. In the rich text field, after selecting text to make it bold/italics/underline and then click respective button from the popup window nothing happens.

Comment: That might be a bug especially if that field is configured to allow bold, italics, and underline. Also double check it just isn't styling that prevents displaying bold by saving changes and checking the Component's form view. If it's really not making the change, log a ticket with SDL Support.

Comment: @NitinChaurasia, can you tag the question with the product version in use, please include Service Pack and Hotfix Rollup versions if applicable, thanks.

Comment: It works for me. On popup as well as from the ribbon bar. So, please check if you are seeing some errors on the DOM

Comment: Below hotfixes are applied:
CME_2013.1.0.88115
CM_2013.1.0.87500
CME_2013.1.0.88281

@Vipin
I found below error in DOM:
http://trdioncms/SDL/Common/ApplicationHost/ApplicationHost/Views/Frame/cultures/frame.en-US.js?1.0.0.1253  404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the errors that you see on the DOM? It is difficult to read it from the comment.

Comment: This might help http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/404s-appearing-in-console-when-loading-xpm