# XPM Issue: JavaScript security errors when clicking Update Preview

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

I'm trying to configure Experience Manager on a 2013 SP1 DD4T Website.

I thought I had it working for a while but now I am getting a few different errors in different browsers.

In Chrome, when I click "Update Preview" I see the following error and the browser never finishes the "Loading.." overlay.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://tridion-web-dev.client.co.uk" from accessing a frame with
>   origin "http://tridion-web-dev.client.co.uk". The frame requesting
>   access set "document.domain" to "client.co.uk", but the frame
>   being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same
>   value to allow access.

The source seems to be on this line:

```
:function(e){var a=window.parent.frames["cookie_cleaner"]
```

In IE, I get Access Denied on similar lines.

[image]

I am also seeing this issue with the missing culture file. [404s appearing in console when loading XPM](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/404s-appearing-in-console-when-loading-xpm)

se_blank.html is definitely serving a 200 OK.

I feel like I'm going round in circles. Any ideas?

I've followed all the usual guides and double checked my config.

Comment: I remember I had a similar issue with the frames and we had to configure IIS to set some header (sorry i can't remember more than this). Have you tried searching outside the Tridion scope, i.e. generic web stuff related to this error?

Comment: Thanks Nick, I think I've got somewhere, I've found some custom code in the app that is setting document.domain - I think this is conflicting with XPM... Unfortunately I didn't write the code. May have to wrap it in "if(isSiteEditEnabled)" or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to be caused by some JavaScript code which was manually setting the `document.domain` to "client.co.uk". This was to enable some cross domain communication between subdomains.

This meant that the iframe which XPM uses and the CME could not properly communicate.

Removing this code made it work but I need that code to run in a non-XPM context. I will need to add something to check if we're in XPM mode or not.

Comment: Take a look at the comments around the "IsPreview" property here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/5ba62d9640c11efa3ed6bca801777c6d8c6c2ea6/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Configuration/WebRequestContext.cs